# Vundle installation fail?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to install Vundle following the instruction from [here](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#about) , but when I use the command, `vim +PluginInstall +qall`  terminal shows this:

```
Error detected while processing /home/scorpion/.vimrc:
line    6:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#begin
line   11:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
line   16:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
line   18:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'L9'
line   20:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
line   22:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
line   25:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
line   28:
E492: Not an editor command: Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}
line   31:
E117: Unknown function: vundle#end
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

I'm new at this . What is the possible problem here ? How could I solve them?
How could I be ensure that my Vundle is installed properly ?

content of `.vimrc` is

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" git repos on your local machine (i.e. when working on your own plugin)
" Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'
" The sparkup vim script is in a subdirectory of this repo called vim.
" Pass the path to set the runtimepath properly.
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
" Install L9 and avoid a Naming conflict if you've already installed a
" different version somewhere else.
Plugin 'ascenator/L9', {'name': 'newL9'}

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal "
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to add the content of the screenshot, DONT post pictures of just text.

Comment: Please go through the installation steps again may be you missed something...

Comment: @M.Becerra , The link I include contains all the contents , thats why I do not include them. When I use 'git clone'  command, it did not give any error or warning. if you still think that I had to include that screen shot too, let me know.  I also check that git and Curl are installed .

Comment: The link you include does not contain the error messages you get in the terminal, which is the text that should be copy/pasted :)

Comment: @George , I go through the process couple of times. Even I removed vim, auto clean and start from the scratch. I dont know what I'm missing.

Comment: @M.Becerra , may be I did not get it. I think the screen shot i provide is all the error message. Is there any other way to get more info about the error. I'm a new bee at using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, there is, copy the output you get from running `vim +PluginInstall +qall` and paste it to replace the screenshot. The site will automatically search for related questions/answers, which could help you, using such text :)

Comment: Please post the content of the `.vimrc`

Comment: Ok please run this `:PluginInstall` from vim

Comment: I did that too. It says  ' E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall '  .

Comment: Now remove all between `call vundle#begin()`, and `call vundle#end()`. Hence remove all plugins and try again...

Comment: Please post the contents of  `.vimrc`!

Comment: removing those lines stops the errors. But how could I know that Vundle will work properly and have no trouble for removing those lines.

Comment: Please remove the `plugins` you have there and source `.vimrc`

Comment: Ok, add each plugin one after the other and note which one gives an erro after addition

Comment: Do you have this `Plugin 'file:///home/gmarik/path/to/plugin'`, are you __gmark__ and have you such a path?

Comment: I don't get what you meant by `are you _gmark_ ' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55549/discussion-between-george-and-anklon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my interaction the `~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` was not yet set up. So these are the steps to setup *VundleVim*.

1. Create `/home/$USER/.vim/bundle`

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/$USER/.vim/bundle
   ```
2. Clone the git repository into bundle directory:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
   ```
3. Now create a `.vimrc` file if not there:

   ```
   touch /home/$USER/.vimrc
   ```
4. Add these lines to it:

   ```
   " no vi compat
   set nocompatible

   " filetype func off
   filetype off

   " initialize vundle
   set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

   call vundle#begin()
   " start- all plugins below

   Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
   Plugin 'mattn/emmet-vim'        
   Plugin 'morhetz/gruvbox'
   Plugin 'itchyny/lightline.vim'
   Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
   Plugin 'davidhalter/jedi-vim'
   Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
   Plugin 'groenewege/vim-less'
   Plugin 'taglist.vim'
   Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
   Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter' " http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-gutter
   Plugin 'wincent/command-t'      " fast buffer browser

   " stop - all plugins above
   call vundle#end()


   " filetype func on
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
5. Now run `vim +PluginInstall +qall` from the terminal or from within `vim`, `:PluginInstall`

Note: These are the basic configuration to get `VundleVim` working and I have added my own plugins you will need to add yours. Get more plgins from [here](http://vimawesome.com/).

Source:

https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim